# How to automatically create Git repo and checkout files similar to TFS

Tags: git, github, tfs, azure-devops, version-control

I have an automated tool that creates a workspace in TFS, checks out the solution and modifies it as needed based on other inputs. I was using TfsTeamProjectCollection as well as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client class to do most of the work. Here's a sample of what my code did.

```
public void CreateWorkspace()
        {
            this.teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(AzureDeployHelperDefinitionData.TFS_URL));

            this.versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            this.BaseSourcePath = string.Format(@"blah", "blah", this.Branch);
            
            this.Workspace = this.versionControlServer.QueryWorkspaces( this.WorkspaceName, this.versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser,null ).FirstOrDefault() ??
                this.versionControlServer.CreateWorkspace( this.WorkspaceName, this.versionControlServer.AuthorizedUser, this.WorkspaceComment );

            var items = this.versionControlServer.GetItems( this.BaseSourcePath, this.version, RecursionType.OneLevel );
            if( items == null || !items.Items.Any() )
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException( "Unable to get workspace items." );
            }
```

We have now moved all our source code to Git. Does anyone have experience doing something similar in Git? Are there Git specific libraries that I can use to do similar things. If so, can you please point me in the right direction?

My goal is to check  out the solution automatically using another tool (c# based) that I created and add files to that solution as needed. Similar to what I am doing above in TFS, I want to now do in Git.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: Something to consider, is that shell scripts are typically easier to write, test, and maintain when dealing with Git commands. You could still call your program from the script to do the "guts" of the changes as it did before. This may save you a lot of time an effort in the long run.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to Git so I'm still in the process of understanding all this but i've tried the below VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/{collection}"), new VssCredentials());
GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
GitRepository newRepo = new GitRepository() { Name = "newRepo" };
await gitClient.CreateRepositoryAsync(newRepo, "teamProjectName");

Answer (score 0):

Git in Azure DevOps is standard Git. You can use Git commands to clone the repo from DevOps, add files and push the commits:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git

Or use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) with Azure DevOps Service. Client sample for Git, you can refer to the following link:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/tree/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/Git

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Microsoft.Azure.DevOps.ClientSamples.Git
{
    [ClientSample(GitWebApiConstants.AreaName, "items")]
    public class ItemsSample : ClientSample
    {
        [ClientSampleMethod]
        public IEnumerable<GitItem> ListItems()
        {
            VssConnection connection = this.Context.Connection;
            GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

            TeamProjectReference project = ClientSampleHelpers.FindAnyProject(this.Context);
            GitRepository repo = GitSampleHelpers.FindAnyRepository(this.Context, project.Id);

            List<GitItem> items = gitClient.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/", recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.OneLevel).Result;

            Console.WriteLine("project {0}, repo {1}", project.Name, repo.Name);
            foreach(GitItem item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.GitObjectType, item.ObjectId, item.Path);
            }

            return items;            
        }

        [ClientSampleMethod]
        public GitItem GetItem()
        {
            VssConnection connection = this.Context.Connection;
            GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

            TeamProjectReference project = ClientSampleHelpers.FindAnyProject(this.Context);
            GitRepository repo = GitSampleHelpers.FindAnyRepository(this.Context, project.Id);

            // get a filename we know exists
            string filename = gitClient.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/", recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.OneLevel).Result
                .Where(o => o.GitObjectType == GitObjectType.Blob).FirstOrDefault().Path;

            // retrieve the contents of the file
            GitItem item = gitClient.GetItemAsync(repo.Id, filename, includeContent: true).Result;

            Console.WriteLine("File {0} at commit {1} is of length {2}", filename, item.CommitId, item.Content.Length);

            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for  the links above.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do that automatically similar to what I am doing above with TFS. My goal is to check  out the solution automatically using another tool (c# based) that I created and add files to that solution as needed

Comment: Check the link of Client sample for Git I provided in the reply.